# Augment Interesting Tags Feature

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I love the interesting tags feature on the site.  It really helps me see questions on the site that I can answer.

I do wish that I had a bit more power though.  I would like to be able to set up `and` relationships for interesting tags.

For example, I might be interested in questions tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).  I can't answer all C# questions, and I can't answer all regex questions, but I could probably answer almost all [c#+regex](/questions/tagged/c%23%2bregex) questions.